# Eclipse, how to store spinner to database

Tags: android, sql, eclipse

I know how to store a spinner value to string to SQLite Database, but the method is different for database through http. I'd like to know what I'm missing in the code, not sure if the lines I wrote is correct either. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Here is the Activity

```
public class RegisterUser extends Activity implements OnClickListener, AsyncTaskComplete, OnItemSelectedListener{

    private User user = null;
    private Spinner mGender;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_user);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        user = (User)i.getSerializableExtra("User");

        if (user != null) {
            ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.eemail)).setText(user.getEmail());
            ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.repass)).setText(user.getPassword());
            ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.efname)).setText(user.getFirstname());
            ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.elname)).setText(user.getLastname());
            ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.edob)).setText(user.getDob());
            //((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1).setText(user.getGender());

            mGender = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            // Spinner method to read the on selected value
            ArrayAdapter<State> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<State>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new State[] { 
                    new State("Male"), 
                    new State("Female")
                }
            );
            mGender.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
            mGender.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        }

        // set onclick listeners
        findViewById(R.id.buttonNext).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {
            case R.id.buttonNext:
            PostUser();
            break;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void PostUser() {
        // Initialize HttpGet
        CloudDBPost httppost = new CloudDBPost(this, this);

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> lst = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        // add url part
        lst.add(new BasicNameValuePair("url", "http://www.stepsaway.vrgnetwork.com/users/add"));


        lst.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.eemail)).getText().toString().trim()));
        lst.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pass", ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.repass)).getText().toString().trim()));
        lst.add(new BasicNameValuePair("firstname", ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.efname)).getText().toString().trim()));
        lst.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lastname", ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.elname)).getText().toString().trim()));
        lst.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dob", ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.edob)).getText().toString().trim()));
        lst.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender", mGender.getSelectedItem().toString().trim()));


        // add file part
        //lst.add(new BasicNameValuePair("file", "/storage/sdcard/Pictures/icon1.png"));

        httppost.execute(lst);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAsyncTaskComplete (String result) {   
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.d("SaveUser", result);

        if (result.trim().toString().equals("OK")) {
            // start view contacts activity
            Intent contacts = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), GameActivity.class);
            contacts.putExtra("userid", user.getUserid());
            startActivity(contacts);
        } else {
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterUser.this);
            adb.setTitle("Save User");
            adb.setMessage("Unable to save User successfully");
            adb.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
            adb.show();   
        }
    }

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Get the currently selected State object from the spinner
        State st = (State)mGender.getSelectedItem();

        // Show it via a toast
        toastState( "onItemSelected", st );
    } 

    public void toastState(String name, State st) {
        if ( st != null ) {
            //gender = st.name;
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Gen, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

These are the strings:

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    private String userid;
    private String email;
    private String pass;
    private String fname;
    private String lname;
    private String dob;
    private String gender;
    private String locationid;
    private String latitude;
    private String longitude;
    static final long serialVersionUID = 99L;

    public User() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        userid = "0";
        locationid = "0";
        latitude = "0";
        longitude = "0";
    }

    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return pass;
    }

    public void setPassword(String pass) {
        this.pass = pass;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return fname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public static long getSerialVersionUID() {
        return serialVersionUID;
    }

    public String getLocationid() {
        return locationid;
    }

    public void setLocationid(String locationid) {
        this.locationid = locationid;
    }

    public String getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public String getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is store the index that the spinner is currently set to. You can get the current index with [getSelectedItemPosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition%28%29) When you rebuild your view, and you want to restore the spinner to the proper value, pass that stored index into [setSelection()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setSelection%28int%29).